# Individual hit gene information from qblast xml output

Tags: xml, biopython, ncbi

I've just started using Biopython, and I am trying to perform remote BLAST operations using the [`qblast()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast.NCBIWWW-module.html#qblast) function. Everything seems to be working properly, but I am not being able to retrieve an essential output result. When performing the BLAST from the NCBI webpage, I can see the "Features" field for each hit, that indicates the gene, for a given hit subject, assigned to the query nucleotide sequence. However, when parsing the output XML file from `qblast`, I see no field that corresponds to this. I have exported the XML file directly from a BLAST output, and it is missing there as well.

Is it possible that such a crucial piece of information is missing entirely from this output file? Is there an alternative way to access this information, or can I only access it by parsing the output file in text form?

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have the XML obtained from the `qblast()`:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML


xml = NCBIXML.parse(your_xml_handler)

for blast in xml:     
    for hit in blast.alignments:
        # Each hit is a Blast.Record.Alignment
        # http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast.Record.Alignment-class.html
        # Here you can obtain the hit id
        # Something like "gi|588481781|gb|KF958277.1|"
        id = hit.hit_id
        for hsp in hit.hsps:
            # Here you have access to each HSP
            # http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast.Record.HSP-class.html
            start = hsp.sbjct_start
            end = hsp.sbjct_end
```

With the id, start and end you can query the database to get the gene information. This is how it's done in a WebBlast (probably), but they provide a shortcut for "Features".